# Unable to find 'endstream' marker for obj starting at 13367

Tags: python, pdf-generation, python-3.7, pypdf, pypdf4

When executing this piece of code:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader,PdfWriter
import traceback

try:
    input_pdf = PdfReader(dwnld_filepath)
    output_pdf = PdfWriter()
    image = input_pdf.pages[0]
    output_pdf.add_page(image)
    output_pdf.write(file_path)
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

This is the complete traceback I see:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/shafeerali/Documents/Nanonets/avanto/API/test.py", line 58, in
>
> output_pdf.add_page(image)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/_writer.py",
> line 418, in add_page
> return self._add_page(page, list.append, excluded_keys)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/_writer.py",
> line 331, in *add_page
> page = cast("PageObject", page_org.clone(self, False, excluded_keys))   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/generic/*data_structures.py",
> line 199, in clone
> d**._clone(self, pdf_dest, force_duplicate, ignore_fields, visited)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/generic/_data_structures.py",
> line 310, in *clone
> v.clone(pdf_dest, force_duplicate, ignore_fields)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/generic/*data_structures.py",
> line 199, in clone
> d**._clone(self, pdf_dest, force_duplicate, ignore_fields, visited)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/generic/_data_structures.py",
> line 310, in *clone
> v.clone(pdf_dest, force_duplicate, ignore_fields)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/generic/*data_structures.py",
> line 199, in clone
> d**._clone(self, pdf_dest, force_duplicate, ignore_fields, visited)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/generic/_data_structures.py",
> line 310, in _clone
> v.clone(pdf_dest, force_duplicate, ignore_fields)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/generic/_base.py",
> line 300, in clone
> obj.clone(pdf_dest, force_duplicate, ignore_fields)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/generic/_data_structures.py",
> line 116, in clone
> arr.append(data.clone(pdf_dest, force_duplicate, ignore_fields))   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/generic/_base.py",
> line 292, in clone
> obj = self.get_object()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/generic/_base.py",
> line 312, in get_object
> obj = self.pdf.get_object(self)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/_reader.py",
> line 1401, in get_object
> retval = read_object(self.stream, self)  # type: ignore   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/generic/_data_structures.py",
> line 1280, in read_object
> return DictionaryObject.read_from_stream(stream, pdf, forced_encoding)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/generic/_data_structures.py",
> line 538, in read_from_stream
> data["**streamdata**"] = read_unsized_from_steam(stream, pdf)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pypdf/generic/_data_structures.py",
> line 432, in read_unsized_from_steam
> raise PdfReadError( pypdf.errors.PdfReadError: Unable to find 'endstream' marker for obj starting at 13367.

here the PDF file(s) that cause the issue.

[EveBest.pdf](https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/files/13544144/EveBest.pdf)

Comment: Your PDF is broken. The stream in which the error occurred has more data than claimed. Furthermore, there are some loose fragments of PDF syntax in the file. Please ask the source of that PDF for a valid PDF.

Comment: Qpdf appears to be able to mend this file: `qpdf EveBest.pdf out.pdf`. The result visually looks the same as loading the original file into Adobe Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of pypdf (and PyPDF2).

The Traceback indicates that your PDF is broken. You can verify that with PDF validators like https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx

Although pypdf can deal with many issues, it will never be able to deal with all kinds of broken PDF documents.

You can repair PDF documents: [How can I fix/repair a corrupted PDF file?](https://superuser.com/q/278562)